# Is it possible to make Spark run whole Taskset on a single executor?

Tags: apache-spark, taskmanager, apache-spark-standalone

I run a single spark job on a local cluster(1 master-2workers/executors).

From what i have understood until now, all stages of a job are splited into tasks. Each stage has its own task set. Each task of this TaskSet will be scheduled on an executor of the local cluster.

I want to make TaskSetManager of Spark to schedule all tasks of a TaskSet(of a single Stage) on the same (local) executor, but i have not figured up how to do so.

Thanks,
Jim

Comment: Why do you want to do that ? You don't want parallel processing ?

Comment: I want to understand how to it works in order to insert my policy for scheduling of tasks on executors.

Comment: I'd like to take control from spark and be the one who determines which executor will execute each task of a stage.

Comment: I'm not sure that this configurable but you can always read the task manager implementation [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/scheduler/TaskSchedulerImpl.scala)

Answer (score 0):

while submitting the job , provide the number of executors as one

Comment: I appreciate your answer Kiran, but i want to intervene into Spark-core in order to apply the aforementioned plan of execution.